# How to know the caller application of the dll in delphi

Tags: delphi

I have a dll that can be called from different exe applications (dll and exe's are written in Delphi 5).
Is it possible to know inside the dll which exe application it was called from?
In other words let's say I have App1.exe, App2.exe and MyDll.dll. App1.exe called the MyDll.exe. I want to know inside the dll that it was called from App1 but not from App2.

Comment: Can you provide some code?

Comment: The DLL should not care who the caller is, but if it needs to know it should provide a method that the app can use to provide that information. To be clear, if I write a DLL that provides licensing information, I shouldn't care if the app that calls the DLL is named *Project1.exe* or *SomeApp.exe* - all I should care about is that the app calling me provides information that says it's authorized to use my DLL.

Comment: Sure, when it is possible to do so, like when you control both DLL and EXE development. For example, when writing Shell Extension DLLs, it is sometimes useful/needed to detect if the DLL was loaded by explorer.exe itself, and if not then reject loading so as not to be loaded in processes that use OS dialogs hosting instances of explorer, like open/save file dialogs.  You can't ask explorer to call extra functions that you could export. Just saying, detection of the loading process from within the DLL has its uses, even if not commonly done.

Answer (score 2):

If you call the Windows API function [GetModuleFileName()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683197.aspx) passing `NULL` (0) as the module handle (first parameter) then this will return the filename of the **process**, i.e. the executable:

```
function GetProcessFileName: String;
var
  buf: array[0..MAX_PATH-1] of Char;
begin
  GetModuleFileName(0, @buf, Length(buf));
  result := buf;
end;
```

**NOTE:** As Raymond Chen always says, sample programs do little or no error checking!  :)

For further information on the use of this API consult the documentation and use accordingly.

Comment: Since the DLL is written in Delphi, it can alternatively use the [`ParamStr()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.ParamStr) function.  When its `Index` parameter is 0, it returns the full path and filename of the calling process (using `GetModuleFileName(0, ...)`, as shown above), eg: `function GetProcessFilename: String; begin Result := ParamStr(0); end;`

Comment: @David - Thanks for the cleanup.